# Skype won't open on macOS Catalina

Tags: catalina, crash, skype

I'm on macOS Catalina. Recently Skype has stopped opening.

It appears to work then immediately quits.

- I tried look into privacy, I see nothing there.
- I tried reboot same result.
- I tried reinstall also same result.

[image]

## What is going on here ?

---

## Try#1

Reinstall a new Skype, same issue

---

## Try#2

Tried launching the executable file, same issue.

[image]

```
 ~  /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/MacOS/Skype ; e 
    Segmentation fault: 11
    logout
    Saving session...
    ...copying shared history...
    ...saving history...truncating history files...
    ...completed.
```

[Process completed]

---

## Try#3

I tried to `chmod a+x /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/MacOS/Skype`

Rerun, same result, auto Quit

Comment: Will this help ? - https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA10041/why-isn-t-skype-starting-on-my-desktop

Comment: I don't think the step applied to my version of OSX (Catalina), I can't find what they suggested.

Comment: @kyo go to Skype's  parent directory, right click on skype, show package contents, contents, macOS, executable. see if it runs

Comment: Catalina doesn't support 32-bit apps. Is that the issue here?

Comment: @Udhy, I've tried that option not working.

Comment: @ankii : I tried that I got 

xit;~  /Applications/Skype.app/Contents/MacOS/Skype ; e 
Segmentation fault: 11
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]

Comment: @Udhy I added the result of your suggestion on the post, so you can see in a better format.

Comment: @X_841, I am not sure. I think it is working. I've been working, and all of sudden it stopped. I have no idea why.

Comment: seg fault is the problem in their code. You should file a bug report. For a sanity check, how did you uninstall the app?